# Solving $(x-1)y'' -xy' +y = 0$ using Frobenius Series

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

I wish to solve $(x-1)y'' -xy' +y = 0$ using Frobenius series. The issue I am running into is the $x$ coefficient of the first derivative as I wish to find a solution centered at $x=1$. How would one take care of this? Can you express $x$ as a finite power series of $x = (x-1) + (x-1)^0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see... we start with $z=x-1$. Then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}$$
And so
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}$$
So that
$$z\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-(z+1)\frac{dy}{dz}+y=0$$
We let
$$y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^{k+r}$$
Which leads to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+r)(k+r-1)a_kz^{k+r-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+r)a_kz^{k+r}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+r)a_kz^{k+r-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^{k+r}=0$$
The coefficient of $a_0z^{r-1}$ is $r(r-1)-r=r(r-2)=0$, so the difference between the roots is an integer. But we catch a break: for $k\ge1$ matching coefficients of like powers of $z$ we get
$$\left[(k+r+1)(k+r)-(k+r+1)\right]a_{k+1}=(k+r+1)(k+r-1)a_{k+1}=(k+r-1)a_k$$
Thus if $r=0$ and $k=1$ we find that $a_2$ is unconstrained so there is no logarithmic solution. We could start with $r=0$ so that $a_1=a_0$ and then let the unconstrained $a_2=0$. This yields the solution $y=a_0(z+1)=a_0x$. Or we could let the indeterminate
$$\frac{k+r-1}{k+r-1}=1$$
even when $k=1$ and $r=0$. This leads to
$$(k+1)a_{k+1}=\frac{(k+1)!}{k!}a_{k+1}=a_k$$
so
$$(k+1)!a_{k+1}=k!a_k=0!a_0=a_0$$
and we have
$$a_k=\frac{a_0}{k!}$$
which results in
$$y=a_0\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}=a_0e^z=\frac{a_0}ee^x$$
Our overall solution is thus
$$y=c_1x+c_2e^x$$
confirmed by differentiation. Now, can you edit your post to explain where you encountered a problem with all of this?

Comment: I have gotten up to the equality $(k+r+1)(k+r-1)a_{k+1} = (k + r - 1)a_k$. Afterwards I simplified and let $r = 2$ to get $a_{k+1} = \frac{a_k}{k+3}$, which leads to $a_k = \frac{2a_0}{(k+3)!}$. I am not sure where to go from here as this does not lead to a closed form solution.

Comment: I should add I can find the exponential series for $r = 0$, but I cannot see how $a_2$ is unconstrained for $r = 2$. What if we choose $a_0 \neq 0$?

Comment: $a_2$ is unconstrained for $r=\color{red}{0}$ because then $(1+0+1)(1+0-1)a_2=(1+0-1)a_1$. I will edit in a clarification.

Comment: Thank you, so we don't use the root $r=2$ at all? When I go through and carry out the calculations for $r = 2$ I actually obtain your solution, the sum of two linearly independent solutions, meaning I don't need to carry out the calculations for $r = 0$?

Comment: Starting with $r=2$ you get something like $2a_0(e^{x-1}-x)$ so you need to do $r=0$ to get a solution that doesn't have the factor $(x-1)^2$ in it. Stating from $r=0$ you can get two independent solutions as shown.

Comment: That is what I got when I used $r=2$. What do you mean by "doesn't have the factor $(x-1)^2$"?$. Does $2a_0(e^{x-1}-x)$ not represent two linearly independent solutions?